# Help with SQL statement (Select users who have product A, but NOT product B, C or D)

Tags: mysql

> Table 1: users 
>   Fields: id, email, first_name
>
> Table 2: resources 
>   Fields: user_id, product_id

I want to select email, first_name from users table where the user has product_id 22 BUT NOT product ID 1, 3 or 35

What's the SQL to pull this list?

Comment: Edited the question to add ID field to users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select email, first_name 
from users
where id in (select user_id from resources where product_id=22)
and id not in (select user_id from resources where product_id IN (1,3,35))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.email,
       u.first_name
FROM   users u
       JOIN resources r
         ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE  product_id IN ( 1, 3, 22, 35 )
GROUP  BY u.id,
          u.email,
          u.first_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id = 1)
       AND MAX(product_id) = 22
```